# Project disappers from workspace

Tags: aptana3

Aptana 3 was working alright until today. Im on Ubuntu 11.10 using Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.7.201112281312

While Aptana is loading, the projects can be seen in the workspace area on the resource perspective, but when the loading gets completed , projects disappears and just the Local Filesystem is shown.

If any one knows how to get around this bug so that I can atlaest open the projects ?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, and I fixed it by doing this:

1. go to the project explorer, click in the small triangle that it has
   in the top right corner
2. choose the top level elements option
3. select projects (working sets was selected I don't know why)

And that solved the problem for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: Five years later, and this answer just helped me. What a counterintuitive problem to have.